# How to obtain underlying observable value when using .extend?

Tags: knockout.js

I have an observable with a length in **mm** that is extended to let the user use **inch** as well (this works fine). The problem is that I want to use only **mm** for calculation on the server, but when I read the variable, I get the value that is shown for the user.

Is there an easy way to obtain the underlying observable value and avoid the `.extend` function?

**edit:** I solved that problem in my case by adding a new function (*TypeScript* users: watch out and use an interface (see below) to `ko.subscribable.fn` that takes the conversion factor as parameter and calculates it back. So I can call `observable.getMetric(factor)` and receive the value.

**Addendum** Since it took me some time: In TypeScript an Interface like this is needed before the function may be added:

```
interface KnockoutSubscribableFunctions<T> {
    getMetricValue(divisor): number;
}
```

Comment: Modify your extender to store the original observable as a property of the extended observable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't. Your best bet would be to just use a computed to display the length in either mm or inch depending on the user's selection, and always store the length in mm.

You could still use an extender to create the computed. That way, the functionality is at least reusable and you don't have to manually create the same computed variable every time.

```
ko.extenders.unit = function(target, option) {
    return ko.pureComputed({
        read: function () {
            if (option.unit() === 'mm') {
                return option.target();
            } else {
                return parseFloat(option.target() * 0.039).toFixed(2);
            }
        },
        write: function(newVal) {
            if (option.unit() == 'mm') {
                option.target(newVal);
            } else {
                option.target(parseFloat(newVal * 25.4).toFixed(2));
            }
        }
    });
}

function ViewModel() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.lengthMM = ko.observable(10);
    vm.unit = ko.observable('mm');
    vm.displayLength = ko.observable().extend({ unit: { target: vm.lengthMM, unit: vm.unit } });
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/thebluenile/L82qn1fb/

Comment: Thanks for that definite statement. In the meantime it dawned on me that every read operation goes through the extender.